# When I press U the "UV Mapping" menu does not show up

Tags: texturing, uv

[image]When I press <kbd>U</kbd> on my keyboard to project it from view the "UV Mappings" menu just doesn't show up at all.
Any answers on how to fix this?

Comment: Screenshot? Are you in *Edit* mode?

Answer (score 1):

You are in edit mode on a Metaball object. The only objects which you can edit the UVs are mesh object. But you can convert that metaball into a mesh:

- Switch to object mode with <kbd>↹ Tab</kbd>
- <kbd>[image: RMB] RMB</kbd> > Convert To > Mesh